# Implementing Search Bar on UITableView Objective C - iOS 9 or later

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, firebase

I have created an app where I am using google firebase for backend and Objective-C for front-end.

It successfully storing and displaying data on UITableView.

Now, I am trying to **add Search Bar** above the table view and tried many examples from the internet but most of them are outdated.

Can anyone please help me with, how I can add search bar above the table view in **Objective-C** for iOS 9 or later?

Also, How to filter data when we type in the search bar?

Thanks Heaps

Comment: Just add searchbar above the tableview (drag and drop).

Comment: It's easy! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare in .h file:

```
    BOOL isFiltered;
    NSMutableArray *arrsearchresult ,*arrsearchname;
    NSMutableArray *arrfullname;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblAppoinment;
```

Declare in .m file:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
                {
                    // Return the number of rows in the section.
                    /*if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
                     return [arrsearchresult count];

                     } else {
                     return [arrfullname count];
                     }*/

                    if(isFiltered)
                    {
                        return [arrsearchresult count];
                    }

                    return [arrfullname count];
                }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    


static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    AppoinmentTableViewCell *cell = (AppoinmentTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AppoinmentTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        if(isFiltered)
            {
                cell.lblFullname.text = [arrsearchresult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            }




    }

    if(isFiltered)
     {
      cell.lblFullname.text = [arrsearchname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


     }
   }




                - (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
                    isFiltered = YES;
                }



                - (void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
                {



                            if(searchText.length==0)
                            {
                                isFiltered=NO;
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                isFiltered=YES;
                                arrsearchresult=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                                arrsearchdate=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                                arrsearchname=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                                for ( NSString * str in arrfullname)
                                {
                                    NSRange stringRange = [str rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

                                    NSInteger index;
                                    if(stringRange.location != NSNotFound)
                                    {
                                        [arrsearchresult addObject:str];
                                        index = [arrfullname indexOfObject:str];
                                        [arrsearchdate addObject:[arrleadCreatedDate objectAtIndex:index]];
                                        [arrsearchname addObject:str];
                                    }
                                }
                            }



                    [self.tblAppoinment reloadData];
                }

                -(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
                    [self.tblAppoinment resignFirstResponder];
                }

                - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
                    isFiltered=NO;
                    [self.tblAppoinment reloadData];

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you are talking about search bar. but according to your requirement, it's better to use **Search Controller** than search bar standalone. Because there are many delegates method you will find along with these.So you don't have to take headache for extra effort.

Comment: Any idea, how we can filter when we type in search controller?

Answer (score 0):

This code is for filter array.

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:
(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
     NSArray *resultarray;

     NSString *strSearch = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",searchB.text];

      if ([strSearch isEqualToString:@""])
      {
         [self showAllData];

         return;
      }

     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS[cd] %@",strSearch];

     resultarray = [self.arrayALLData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

     [self.arrayPeopleList removeAllObjects];

     [self.arrayPeopleList addObjectsFromArray:resultarray];

     [_tblView reloadData];

     return YES;
}
```

Comment: This search will work if you have string array like @[@"jignesh",@"mayani",@"Rajesh"]

Comment: Thanks Jignesh, It helped me... now my code is not crashing after using this method. I am still playing with it

Comment: I am trying to fetch an array from backend services like google firebase.. do you think I need to use some different approach as you said it will work with string array?

Comment: I will share my code soon, let me try some more stuff... Thanks Mate